# How can I filter my SELECT with ID's not in all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine a table where all the columns are the ID of items at certain places (positions)

```
Select TOP 1 Pos1,Pos2,Pos3,POs4,Pos5,Pos6,Pos7 from tracking order by id desc

|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  Pos1  |  Pos2  |  Pos3  |  Pos4  |  Pos5  |  Pos6  |  Pos7  |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  NULL  |  Item1 |  NULL  | Item 2 |  Item4 |  NULL  | Item 5 |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
```

As you can see, item 3 is nowhere on this table, is "missing"

I have of course a table with all the items

```
Select * from Items

Item1
Item2
Item3
Item4
Item5
```

How can I make a query that will return that my item 3 is missing?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I tried to UNPIVOT my position table and then select ITEMS where itemId not in (????)

But I cannot figure how to make it work, and I don't want to use UNPIVOT

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you want to use UNPIVOT?

Comment: Then use a `VALUES` table construct instead of `UNPIVOT`; I personally prefer this method anyway.

Comment: Also, show us the code you've tried, don't just tell us you've "tried it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return missing items by listing them and using `not exists`:

```
select v.item as missing_item
from (values ('item 3')) v(item)
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where v.item in (pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7)
                 ) ;
```

If you want to look for *all* missing items, then:

```
select i.item as missing_item
from items i
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where i.item in (pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7
                 ) ;
```

Comment: You need to add extra `)` for `NOT EXITS`

Comment: @Ilyes . . . I think I need the extra paren for the `in`.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer columns to line first.

```
    SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT 1 AS lineID,NULL AS Pos1 , 'item1' AS   Pos2 , 'item2'  AS  Pos3 , NULL   Pos4,  'item3' AS   Pos5 , 'item5' AS  Pos6 , 'item10' AS   Pos7  
     ) AS t
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Pos1',t.Pos1),('Pos1',t.Pos2),('Pos1',t.Pos3),('Pos1',t.Pos4),('Pos1',t.Pos5),('Pos1',t.Pos6),('Pos1',t.Pos7)) AS c (colName,ColValue)
    WHERE c.ColValue='item3'
```

SQL2:

```
;WITH t AS 
    (
               SELECT 1 AS lineID,'item0' AS Pos1 , 'item1' AS   Pos2 , 'item2'  AS  Pos3 , 'item4'   Pos4,  'item5' AS   Pos5 , 'item5' AS  Pos6 , 'item7' AS   Pos7  
     )

    SELECT * FROM t
    UNPIVOT
     (
      itemcode
      FOR pos in (pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4,pos5,pos6,pos7)
     ) AS PosUnpivot
     where itemcode='item0'
```